# Please explain how object instantiation works here whilst it's not being used - seemingly

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, mvp

For the code below, how does object `mainPresenter` or `new Presenter(mainView, connectionString)`even work here? The instance is never used. This code is part of a MVP (passive view) in WinForms project I'm doing for practice. I see many people do this but where does the instantiated Presenter object go? What's happening here?

```
using PresentationLayer.Presenters;

namespace PresentationLayer
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
            // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();

            //--------------------------------------------

            string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Music;Integrated Security=True";
            IMainView mainView = new MusicForm();
            Presenter mainPresenter = new Presenter(mainView, connectionString);

            //--------------------------------------------
            Application.Run((Form)(mainView));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the presenter just in case one needs it:

```
using Models;
using ServiceLayer;

namespace PresentationLayer.Presenters
{
    public class Presenter
    {
        private readonly IMainView _mainView;
        private readonly IAlbumRepository _albumRepository;
        private IEnumerable<Album>? _albumList;
        private readonly BindingSource _bindingSource;

        //------------------------------------------------------------
        public Presenter(IMainView mainView, string connectionString) 
        {
            _bindingSource = new BindingSource();
            _mainView = mainView;
            _albumRepository = new AlbumRepository(connectionString);
            _mainView.GetAll += GetAll;
            _mainView.SearchInAlbums += SearchInAlbums;
        }

        //--------------- main functionality --------------------------

        private void GetAll(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _albumList = _albumRepository.GetAll();
            SetBindingSource(_albumList);
        }

        private void SearchInAlbums(object? sender, string fndAlbumsByPhrase)
        {
            _albumList = _albumRepository.SearchByAlbum(fndAlbumsByPhrase);
            SetBindingSource(_albumList);
        }


        //------------------helpers / utilities ------------------------

        private void SetBindingSource(IEnumerable<Album> coll)
        {
            _bindingSource.DataSource = _albumList;
            _mainView.SetAlbumsBindingSource(_bindingSource);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Presenter holds the mainView as a dependency.  That's all you need to make it work.  Application.Run is a blocking call, so the Presenter variable stays in scope and is not garbage-collected until the application exits.

Comment: @RobertHarveyThank you. But what is using that instance? And how? I simply do not understand this line of code. Can you perhaps generate a simple console program illustrating its workings?

Comment: Have a look at the Presenter constructor. You can see that it registers two event handlers (GetAll and SearchInAlbums). There will be event handlers on your MusicForm which exposes GetAll and SearchInAlbum which the presenter will be responsible for.

Comment: I think you're laboring under the assumption that you must do something with that `mainPresenter` variable.  You don't.  It's perfectly feasible to new up an object and use it without ever touching the variable it is assigned to.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes sir. That is exactly what puzzles me.

Comment: @Hayden Wait a minute, so newing up calls its constructor. That is its only purpose in life?

Comment: To answer your question, the `mainPresenter` is initialized so that it can live for the lifetime of the application. This on its own isn't useful except that it hold event handler subscriptions which the Presenter handles. If `mainPresenter` gets disposed, then the event handlers will be disposed too and the logic for `GetAll` and `SearchInAlbums` will not be called from MusicForm. The reason it's done this way is so the UI logic is separated from forms, and can be unit tested more easily and is also a good separation of concerns.

Comment: You can think of `new` as calling the constructor, yes.  It's a little more nuanced than that; classes without a constructor have a default constructor, and there are also `static` constructors.